# How to visually determine when two objects are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I've been working through some of the exercises in the first chapter of Spivak's book *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, and I have a question about three of the exercises that he provides.

> (16) A classical theorem of topology states that every compact surface other than $S^2$ is obtained by gluing together a certain number of tori and projective spaces, and that all compact surfaces-with-boundary are obtained from these by cutting out a finite number of disks. To which of these "standard" surfaces are the following homeomorphic? [image]

> (17) Let $C\subset \mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the Cantor set.  Show that $\mathbb{R}^2-C$ is homeomorphic to the surface shown at the top of the next page. [image]

> (21a) Show that the three open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ shown below are homeomorphic. [image]

What type of argument do problems like these require? Of course, I guess I could make a visual justification for why these objects are homeomorphic, but is there a formal (proof based) way of approaching such problems? If not, is there an elegant way of showing why these drawings are homeomorphic based on visual intuition?

Since I am used to writing proofs in this type of mathematical setting, I feel sort of uncomfortable just making blanket judgments like this based on my visual interpretation instead of making a proper mathematical argument.  Is this unnecessary to do for something like this?

Comment: Given the description at the top, I suspect that you are expected to "count holes":  a surface can be constructed by gluing some number of tori to a sphere, possibly throwing in a Klein bottle, and cutting out some number of holes.  So:  is your surface orientable?  how many handles does it have?  how many holes does it have?  This gives a complete classification of surfaces.

Comment: There is of course a formal way to prove anything, that is the meaning of proof. But topology arguments you see online often use visual intuition in favour of explicitly describing messy pointwise defined functions! I often find it useful to explicitly calculate the homeomorphism functions, though, in favour of just saying "... *clearly*, this can turn into that..." which many authors do for brevity